# Spring cloud Stream kafka binder - Auto-provisioning of topics

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

*Spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka 3.0.9.RELEASE*

Would it be possible to disable the provisioning phase during application start-up?

We have some problems when starting applications with several kafka producers configured, in which during the provisioning phase KafkaProducers are created and closed immediately to obtain information about the topics, partitions... but in many cases the close() of the KafkaProducer takes a long time to close, even exhausting the default 30 seconds of the closeTimeout, slowing down the application at startup.

Moreover, if we deploy in productive environments in which the target topics are already created and are not allowed to be modified, we do not know if the provisioning phase makes sense.

Therefore, is it possible to disable the provisioning phase? In an environment where the topics are already configured and cannot be modified, is the provisioning phase necessary?